# Nullpointerexception in injecting Spring 3 service to JSF 2 ManagedBean

Tags: spring, jsf-2, nullpointerexception, autowired

Actually I have seen a lot of similar questions here. Unfortunately I could not solve the  problem by following the advices. Here are my codes. Could anyone find me where the problem could be? Thanks much.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>co.amity.sales</groupId>
  <artifactId>amitysales</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>amitysales Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
  </repositories>

  <properties>
    <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
    <spring.framework.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>

  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.23</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Primefaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- c3p0 dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency> -->

 </dependencies>




  <build>
    <finalName>amitysales</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:app-context.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>

    <!-- configuration of navigation rules -->
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/success.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

app-contex.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <description>Example configuration to get you started.</description>

    <!-- <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql" />
    </jdbc:embedded-database> -->

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Data Source Declaration -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />   
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sales" />   
        <property name="username" value="root" />   
        <property name="password" value="root" />   
    </bean>

    <bean id="emf"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="co.hyperclean.sales.entity" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="co.hyperclean.sales" />

</beans>
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
package co.hyperclean.sales.service.impl;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import co.hyperclean.sales.entity.Users;
import co.hyperclean.sales.service.UserService;

@Service("jpaUserService")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(UserServiceImpl.class); 

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<Users> findAll() {
        List<Users> contacts = em.createNamedQuery("Users.findAll", Users.class).getResultList();
        return contacts;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public Users findById(int id) {
        TypedQuery<Users> query = em.createNamedQuery("Users.findById", Users.class);
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        return query.getSingleResult();
    }

}
```

UserManagedBean.java

```
package co.hyperclean.sales.jsf.bean;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;

import co.hyperclean.sales.entity.Users;
import co.hyperclean.sales.service.UserService;

@ManagedBean(name="usersManagedBean")
@RequestScoped
public class UsersManagedBean {

    // Spring User Service is injected...
    //@ManagedProperty(value = "#{jpaUserService}")

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    List<Users> userList = new ArrayList<Users>();

    private Users user = new Users();

    public String searchUser() {
        try {
            userList.add(userService.findById(user.getId()));
            return "success";
        } catch (DataAccessException dae) {
            dae.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "error";
    }

    public UserService getUserService() {
        return userService;
    }


    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    public List<Users> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }
    public void setUserList(List<Users> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    public Users getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Users user) {
        this.user = user;
    }


}
```

Comment: The problem is you trying to inject with @autowired. Use @managedproperty to inject into jsf.This is not an option.you should use `@managedproperty` only.examplehttp://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/injecting-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: Actually, I also tried with @ManagedProperty too. You can see it is commented out in the snippet. Thanks for the answer and link, I will check it out.

Comment: setUserService(UserService userService) is called but userService is null.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I put faces-config.xml outside of WEB-INF and I didn't read it from web.xml.